# How to create a telnet connection in Delphi applications

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, telnet

I want to create a telnet connection in Delphi that will allow me to connect to the command prompt on my computer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Telnet Client with Delphi 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896069/how-to-create-telnet-client-with-delphi-5)

Comment: Quick answer: You don't, because Delphi generates Win32 exes and Windows doesn't have an Telnet server. Or was that connect to "my other computer"? If so, then question is an duplicate, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a telnet server, Windows XP and newer comes with a telnet service that just needs to be enable and started via the service control manager. It is disabled by default when windows is installed. I recommend against writing your own telnet server unless you really know what you are doing because you are likely to create a lot of security issues.