# Add formatted text to SynEdit

Tags: delphi, synedit

How can I add formatted text to a SynEdit control?  I don't actually need syntax highlighting, I want to be able to control the colors of specific parts of a line.

I am currently using a TRichEdit and setting `SelAttributes.Color` and `SelAttributes.Text` in order to achieve this effect.  It works fine, but I am hoping to get away from using TRichEdit.

Can I do something similar with SynEdit, or is it not the ideal component for the job?

Comment: Maybe you should consider embedding a webbrowser instead. That's probably how I would solve it.

Comment: SynEdit it's basically a code editor. You can control certain properties but usually through a highlighter. Are you trying to create a log viewer?

Comment: @Wouter van Nifterick: I have considered giving that a shot.  Would it be as fast?

Comment: @Leonardo Herrera: I am actually making a MUD client.  I receive text via TCP, and it has ANSI escape codes that signify that certain portions of the text need to be displayed in specific colors.  I parse the text and display it appropriately on the RichEdit.  RichEdit is working fine for now, but I was kicking around the idea of trying to switch to something else, so that my code would be less platform dependent.

Comment: Interesting. There are components that do this, thought (take a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/896220/7841), for example.)

Comment: @Leonardo Herrera What would be your suggestion if this was a log viewer?

Comment: Actually, I'd use a VirtualTree or similar component.